# Keyboard shortcut to extend Google Sheet formula down to the next cell?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a formula in cell A2, say, in a Google Sheet.

With cell A2 selected, is there a keyboard shortcut to extend that formula down to cell A3?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, but it's a series -

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> (select)

then:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> (fill)

Comment: If there are changes in the contents of the column the Shift+Alt+Down will stop selecting at the change. (For instance gaps in input where there was only blanks in that column)
Continuing to hit Down-Arrow will eventually go to the end, but it can be tiresome also.

Comment: What about for mac?

Comment: Fill is ⌘-D on Macs.

Comment: If I have "1, 2, 3" and extend, it'll do 4, 5, 6.... but with ctrl+d it just puts 1 in all of them.